# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'gP1' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, dart-null-safety

Can someone explain to me where I am wrong? I am programming this application and, working with sqflite, I have had this kind of problem several times when I use the `readPlayer()` function.

```
class matchesRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final List matches;
  final List results;
  final int index;
  matchesRow({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
    required this.matches,
    required this.results,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<matchesRow> createState() => _matchesRowState();
}

class _matchesRowState extends State<matchesRow> {
  late Player gP1;
  late Player gP2;
  bool ripescato = false;
  PlayersDatabase pb = PlayersDatabase.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPlayers();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    PlayersDatabase.instance.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future getPlayers() async {
    List<dynamic> duel = widget.matches[widget.index];
    gP1 = await pb.readPlayer(duel[0]);
    print(gP1);
    gP2 = await pb.readPlayer(duel[0]);
    if (duel[1] == "R") {
      ripescato = true;
    } else {
      gP2 = await pb.readPlayer(duel[1]);
    }
  }

  @override
  Container build(BuildContext context) {
    var icon = Icons.code_sharp;
    return Container(child: Text(gP1.name));
  }}
```

This is the function ReadPlayer()

```
Future<Player> readPlayer(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final maps = await db.query(
      tablePlayers,
      columns: PlayerFields.values,
      where: '${PlayerFields.id} = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      return Player.fromJson(maps.first);
    } else {
      throw Exception('ID $id not found');
    }
```

I don't understand why even if I declare the value of gP1 and gP2 in getPlayers() the error still pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gP1` and `gP2` getting from future method. It will take some time to fetch data from future method `getPlayers`. Use FutureBuilder or make it nullable

For nullable case it will be

```dart
    Player? gP1;
    Player? gP2;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPlayers().then((value) {
      //update Ui after getting data
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

And use case with default value on null case

```dart
Text(gP1?.name??"didnt get yet")
```